# Unreachable Statement in fragment activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

What is unreachable statement.
I am not able to use [firebasefirestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSIN7.png) and also [method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDeO2.png) is unreachable statement in **fragment view**.
How to use methods and other things and what is unreachable statement?

```
    private FragmentPostfragBinding binding;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding=FragmentPostfragBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View view=binding.getRoot();
        return view;


        userview();


    }

    private void userview() {
        FirebaseFirestore db;

        db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        DocumentReference ref = db.collection("user").document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        ref.get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if(documentSnapshot.exists()){

                            String name=documentSnapshot.getString("username");
                            binding.user.setText(name);

                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry, your information is not saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),otherinfo.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+e.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Unreachable statement" means you have some code that will never run under any circumstances.  In your case, it's referring to the call to `userview()` which will never run because it follows a `return` statement.  The return will prevent `userview()` from ever being called.

You'll need to figure out what you actually want to happen here, and code it correctly.

Comment: can you describe more, how can i call the method i just want to access database and get a information in a fragment view.

Comment: At the very least, you're going to have to do it before you return from the function.